# Configuring Doctrine 2 with plain Symfony 2 container builder

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm

I'm building a library using Symfony 2 components and at the core I'm using Symfony's dependency injection.

For configuration I simply load a configuration file after my service container creation like this:

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();

$loader = new YamlFileLoader( $container, new FileLocator( $configPath ) );
$loader->load('container.yml');

$this->setContainer( $container );
```

This simply loads all my services. However, I now need to configure Doctrine 2. When I add a basic Doctrine configuration profile:

```
  doctrine:
      dbal:
          default_connection:   default
          connections:
              default:
                  driver:   "%database_driver%"
                  host:     "%database_host%"
                  port:     "%database_port%"
                  dbname:   "%database_name%"
                  user:     "%database_user%"
                  password: "%database_password%"
                  charset:  UTF8
      orm:
          default_entity_manager:   default
          entity_managers:
              default:
                  connection:       default
                  mappings:
                      AcmeDemoBundle: ~
                      AcmeStoreBundle: ~
```

I get the following error when I run my tests:

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "doctrine". Looked for namespace "doctrine", found none
```

I assume I need to write a configuration extension for the "doctrine" profile but I'm stuck on the details on this.

Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a plain container, you have to configure the `doctrine` section yourself. In the Symfony framework it is set up with a dependency injection extension, which you can find in the [DoctrineBundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php) (look in there for insights).

It's so called [semantic configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html).